# Custom Authorization Attribute not working on cached request

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, session, authorization, authorize-attribute

I am working on a small asp.net MVC project. There is a web service that validates a customer. After validating, I am storing user information in Session variable and setting it null after log out. I have a custom Authorization filter like this:

```
public class MgAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
        if (httpContext.Session["Customer"] == null)
        {
            httpContext.Server.TransferRequest("~/Upgrade/Login");
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

The problem is it does not check the user when back button is pressed in the browser. So, the user can access protected pages even after logging out of the application. 
Please suggest me the smartest way to handle the scenario. TIA.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use  `return RedirectToActionPermanent();` to disable the back button. Does this achieve what you want? Let me know.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Actually what I am doing now is something similar - disabling the back button using javascript. But this is not what I want. I don't want to hamper the natural behavior of browser. Rather, I would prefer that, the system is redirected to the login page, whenever the user want to access unauthorized actions.